# git checkout vs git checkout HEAD vs git checkout <CURRENT BRANCH> vs git checkout -- <WORKING DIR>

Tags: git

I'm trying to determine the differences that exist among the following 4 commands.

*Assume that the current branch is `master`, and the current directory is the "working directory", i.e., the one where `.git` is.*

```
git checkout

git checkout HEAD

git checkout master

git checkout -- .
```

As far as I can tell, the first two commands are *completely equivalent*, and are essentially no-op's (except for the fact that they both may produce some output); the third one is almost identical to the first two, except that it will produce, in addition to any other output the former produce, the line `Already on 'master'.`  The last command, in contrast to all the other ones, will discard all the unstaged changes.

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

According to [TFM](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), there are four forms of the `git checkout` command. Your first two examples are one of them, and your other two examples are two more.

So to answer your question, you've missed the last form of `git checkout`:

`git checkout -b <new branch name> <start point>`

Comment: where do you get the "four" from?  the page you linked begins with 5 different patterns involving `git checkout`...

Comment: Scroll down, there are four major paragraphs of description. The mismatch is a little odd, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 are the same (and are *not* no-ops, if you did change some files they will get replaced by the ones in the tip of master). The 4th one checks out *only* the files in '.', i.e., the current directory.